# $http get params is not received by api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am a beginner to angularjs and webapi. I have created below angularjs and webapi. The problem I am facing is that the api object contains just null and no data. could anyone spot what I am doing wrong.

Angular Code:

```
$scope.GetReport = function () {

    var ReportModel = {};
    debugger;
    var result = {};

    if (angular.isDefined($scope.Report.FromDate))
        ReportModel.FromDate = new Date($scope.Report.FromDate);
    else
        ReportModel.FromDate = null;
    if (angular.isDefined($scope.Report.ToDate))
        ReportModel.Todate = new Date($scope.Report.ToDate);
    else
        ReportModel.Todate = null;
    ReportModel.UserID = '';
    ReportModel.UserWWID = '1234';
    ReportModel.UserRole = '';
    ReportModel.ProjectType = '';
    ReportModel.ProjStatus = 'In Progress';
    ReportModel.CreatedBy = '11744439';
    ReportModel.LGroup = '';
    ReportModel.LUnit = '';
    ReportModel.LTeam = '';

    var config = {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
        datatype: JSON,
        data: JSON.stringify(ReportModel)
    };

    result = $http.get('api/Project/GetReport', { params: ReportModel })
                .then(function (response) {
                    result = response.data;
                    })
                }, function (response) {
                    alert('Failed ' + JSON.stringify(response.statusText));
                };
}
```

Web API:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetReport(ViewReportModel objViewRepotModel)
    {
        try
        {
            //Code here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you not using `config object` and post , like `$http.post('api/Project/GetReport', config)` ?

Comment: When writing questions, use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`$http` takes json as default type, so you could comment config and just send `ReportModel` as the payload.

```
//var config = {
//    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
//   datatype: JSON,
//   data: JSON.stringify(ReportModel)
//};


var payload = {reportModel : ReportModel};
result = $http.post('api/Project/GetReport', payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                result = response.data;
                })
            }, function (response) {
                alert('Failed ' + JSON.stringify(response.statusText));
            };
```

Moreover, I'd suggest you to use `$http.Post` here for better security reasons.

Comment: I am already not using the config object and if I pass the way you have showed, I am not even seeing the params in the querystring

Comment: You are not using the base path for the web api, it should be something like `http://localhostxxx/api/Project/GetReport`

Comment: Also, see the change in sending the payload.